# How do I create a "Window" menu in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am creating an MVVM Wpf client application.  I want create menu in the main View for the application that his a menu item called "Window" on it.  That menu item will dynamically update itself with a submenu of menuitems who are made up of the list of active windows running in the application.  I created a ViewManager whom each View registers itself with to compile a list of active windows.

I am trying to do this in XAML but getting an error when I click on "Window"

```
<MenuItem Header="Window">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewMgr.Views}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenWindowCmd , 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</MenuItem>
```

How do I create a dynamically updated list of menuitems on my menu in XAML using a MVVM style of data bindings and commands?

Comment: what kind of error you got? try to get detail of the error message and post it, that usually can help to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new ItemsControl as a single child of the menu item, instead of adding each view as one child of the menu item itself. You probably get the error because the styles `TargetType` doesn't match. `MenuItem` inherits from ItemsControl itself and exposes a property `ItemsSource`. Try the following:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding ViewMgr.Views}" DisplayMemberPath="Title">

    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenWindowCmd,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked!  I edited your xaml and added the header for clarity and fixed the Menu.ItemContainerStyle closing tag which was wrong.

Comment: Hmm, what would you like to add? I can edit the post... Closing tag seems fine to me, though... Cheers!

Comment: Should be </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>